# How to build vim plugin so that users can install it using pathogen

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, pathogen

I wrote code for a vim plugin (in python wrapped in VimL) and now I want to share it with the world. What do I have to do to get it so that other users can install it with pathogen and add it to their vim packages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Pathogen bundle is just files in the same subdirectories as they would be under `$HOME/.vim`. For example, here is the structure of a Pathogen-managed plugin I wrote:

```
.
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── doc
│   └── octopress.txt
├── ftplugin
│   └── octopress.vim
├── plugin
│   └── octopress.vim
└── syntax
    └── octopress.vim
```

I put that tree into `$HOME/.vim/bundle/octopress/` and Pathogen worked it out.

Here's the layout of a more complex plugin, vim-signify, which I have installed in `$HOME/.vim/bundle/signify/`.

```
.
├── CONTRIBUTING.md
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── autoload
│   ├── sy
│   │   ├── debug.vim
│   │   ├── fold.vim
│   │   ├── highlight.vim
│   │   ├── jump.vim
│   │   ├── repo.vim
│   │   ├── sign.vim
│   │   └── util.vim
│   └── sy.vim
├── doc
│   ├── signify.txt
│   └── tags
├── plugin
│   └── signify.vim
├── showcolors.bash
└── signify.gif
```